# Pass input tag value to as href parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass the value of input tag as parameter(quantita) in href.
Should i use javascript to do this?Sorry for my english
Thanks

```
<input type="text" id="qta_field" value="${item.value}"/><a href="updateItem?codice=${item.key.codice}&quantita=">update</a>
```

[image]

Comment: why cant you just use `&quantita=${item.value}` ?

Comment: You want to pass the value when you are submit the form ? When you want to pass this value ?

Comment: The item.value contains a value that can be changed by the user.I insert an image as an example

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way to do it with link and without any library:

```
<input type="text" id="qta_field" value="${item.value}"/>
<a href='' onclick="this.href='updateItem?codice=${item.key.codice}&quantita='+document.getElementById('qta_field').value">update</a>
```

Comment: With your code the "update" link has disappeared.It's not clickable

Comment: Updated: added href='' to <a>

Comment: It works but if i have a list of "update link" it remove only the first

Comment: didn't understand, give me example

Comment: In jsp (cart shopping) i have a list of Articles . I scan the list with foreach tag and with your code i can update only the first article, which is on top of the list .The articles from the second to the last are not updated

Comment: In this line: document.getElementById('qta_field') you are getting input by id, so if you need to get values from other inputs and put to appropriate link (<a>), so you need to chanthe ther id and get appropriate int with id that you need

Comment: This works great. The Javascript "document.getElementById('qta_field').value" would be a little shorter in jQuery as "$('#qta_field').val()"

Answer (score 4):

To send data from an input to the server, you should use a form.

```
<form action="updateItem">

  <input id="qta_field" name="quantita" value="${item.value}">
  <input type="hidden" name="codice" value="${item.key.codice}">

  <button>update</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

set an id or a class to your `<a>` for example : `<a id='myA'>`

So you can use jQuery like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('qta_field').change(function(){
        var tmpVal = jQuery('#qta_field').val();
        var tmphref = jQuery('#myA').attr('href');
        tmphref = tmphref+tmpVal;
        jQuery('#myA').attr('href',tmphref);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the document.queryselector to locate and manipulate the href attribute with js

Example:

```js
input = document.querySelector('input');
a = document.querySelector('a');
a.setAttribute('href',a.getAttribute('href')+input.value);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="qta_field" value="test"/>
<a href="updateItem?codice=${item.key.codice}&quantita=">update</a>
```